# displaying report in mobile device and tab

Tags: android, view, report, document

In my android application, report document is being shown in an activity. 
It is the simple html file.

The problem is:

It is displayed fine when viewed from `mobile device` but when we view the same report from `android tab`, **the black header covers the top part of the report**. I can adjust the display by adding `br` tags on top of html but this will hamper the mobile device view due to the differences in the display size.

It is very inaccurate thing to make the layout for all devices.

What's the best alternative to get the view displayed such that the black header does not cover the top of the report for both the devices without any spaces.

Comment: CSS comes to mind but I'm not even sure from your Q that you use a `WebView`. Also, I can guess what you mean by "mobile device" and "android tab" but I'm not so sure about guessing that right, either. Your choice of tags adds to my confusion; I'd expect someone with so many reputation points to choose relevant tags.

Comment: I have html file in assets folder and it is shown within a simple view container, no webview. The line - `InputStream is = getAssets().open(myreport.html);` opens it with some code to display accordingly and I have jars `itextpdf-5.3.0.jar` and `pdfviewer.jar` to view the pdf report as html.

Comment: "It is very inaccurate thing to make the layout for all devices." I don't see it this way, it's not inaccurate; especially in HTML/CSS there's a broad range of tools to achieve a near-perfect result.

Comment: ok but how to get the perfect result here.

Comment: Ah, we're getting closer. Well, if I had to live with this approach, I'd try two things. 1) Integrate the HTML from the PDF-to-HTML and show it in a WebView and see what I get. 2) Play with CSS until I like the result.

Comment: CSS isn't the problem but how to adjust css according to screen height and width for any device is a problem as you can't set the same css for every device.

Comment: Of course you can use the same CSS for every device and achieve scaling. But that's beyond my time limit for this question. I'll correct the tags for you so there's a higher chance the right people look at it. EDIT: I didn't because you're convinced it's not the right solution. Anyway, good luck!